# How do I set the POST body of a jquery POST request?

Tags: jquery, rest, post

I'm trying to make a POST request using JQuery and the API that I'm reading about says this:

> On your server, you can now make the following request to obtain an
>   access token:
>
> POST https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token
>
> POST Body (URL-encoded)
>
> client_id=[your client ID] &client_secret=[your client secret]
>   &grant_type=authorization_code &redirect_uri=[your registered redirect
>   URI] &code=[code received from redirect URI]

How would this POST request look in javascript? I'm pretty new to JS/Jquery in general so I don't know much about RESTful calls.

This is what I tried:

```
$.post( "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token?client_id=" + clientID 
            + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret 
            + "&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri="+ redirectURI 
            + "&code=" + code, 
            function( data ) {
      grabUserAccessTok(data );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
$.post("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token", {
    client_id: clientID,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    grant_type : authorization_code,
    redirect_uri: redirectURI,
    code: code
  },
  function(data) {
    grabUserAccessTok(data);
  });
```